# Como fazer buscas dentro do código em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, gostaria de fazer um código que quando eu digitasse por exemplo, "nome_do_produto", ele verificasse se existe alguma palavra com o nome que eu digitei e retornasse um valor, exemplo "200 reais". Mas não faço idéia de como começar, ficarei grato se alguém puder me ajudar!

Comment: A resposta do @AntonyGabriel dá o respaldo para a sua necessidade ; dê uma olhada com carinho, estude sobre dicionários em Python, aí você estará preparado para isso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um dicionário para fazer isso que você quer, veja:

```
v = {
     'Celular':"200",
     "Bolsa":"200", 
     "Garrafa":"2"
     }                                    # Os valores também podem ser inteiros
r = input("Digite o valor do produto: ")  # Desde que aqui também seja

print("Por esse preço nós possuimos: \n")
for i in v.keys():
    if r == v[i]:
        print(i)
```

**saída:**

```
>>> Digite o valor do produto: 200
>>> Por esse preço nós possuimos: 
>>> 
>>> Celular
>>> Bolsa
```

Comment: Eu acho que ele queria o contrário ; buscar por nome e obter o valor

Comment: Mas dá pra fazer dessa forma também, é só inverter, no lugar do produto põe o valor e no lugar do valor põe o produto.

Comment: Eu sei, por isso que comentei na pergunta que sua resposta foi linda ;-)

Comment: Eu queria o contrário sim, mas fiz o que @Antony Gabriel falou, inverti. Só uma dúvida, teria como depois que retornasse o valor, pedisse pra digitar outro nome?

Comment: Sim, você pode utilizar um `while` para isso.